# Google Spreadsheet - If() SUM

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Hi I need to do a if statement in my calculation.

Basically what I am trying to do is if I have marked it off as Paid I want to calculate the amount paid and show it as a total.

[image: Google Spreadsheet.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=sumif(H2:H, "Yes",  G2:G)
```

or

```
=sumproduct(H2:H="Yes", G2:G)
```

and see if that works?

Note: Depending on your locale, you may have to change the comma's with semi-colons.